# How to make a sort of scratchboard in flash?

Tags: image, flash, actionscript

I was wondering if someone could teach me how to make a scene in flash where you have an image on top of the other, and you can scratch the top one off to show what's below.

Kinda like those prize cards where you have to scratch the silver thing to see if there's a prize below.

Anyone has any idea if this is even possible in flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, [here](http://www.ilike2flash.com/2009/07/create-scratch-card-in-actionscript-3.html) is one example. I'm sure there are others.

The concept is that you use a mask to hide the image. Then use a mouse move event listener to draw on the mask as the user mouses over the object. Parts of the mask that have something on them (ie: the stuff you're drawing in the mouse move listener) will then reveal the underlying object that was being masked.